# Problema para ejecutar función

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función con el nombre `coinConverter` que convierte el valor de dólares a soles peruanos, pesos mexicano y pesos chilenos.

```
function coinConvert(dollar = 50) {

soles = dollar * 3.25;

 pesosMexicanos = dollar * 18;

 pesosChilenos = dollar * 660;

console.log(soles, pesosMexicanos, pesosChilenos);       
}
```

pero ya en la consola no me da el resultado

Comment: Tu función trabaja bien, lo único que te falta es invocarla justo así: `coinConvert()` al final de tu c´doigo

Comment: Por otro lado edité tu pregunta pues la funcionalidad que buscas no tiene nada que ver con Atom

Comment: gracias, apenas empiezo y tarde  horas en esto aun viendo que la maquina me decía que hacia falta, que boba muchas gracias

Comment: Asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10703962/1595451

Answer (score 3):

El código que has incluído en la pregunta es una declaración de una función. Como se mencionó en un comentario, para que se ejecute debes llamar la función para lo cual hay varias formas de hacerlo. Si deseas que se ejecute inmediatamente al ejecutar el código, incluye un sentencia usando el nombre de la función seguido de paréntesis

```js
function coinConvert(dollar = 50) {

soles = dollar * 3.25;

 pesosMexicanos = dollar * 18;

 pesosChilenos = dollar * 660;

console.log(soles, pesosMexicanos, pesosChilenos);       
}
coinConvert();
```

Otra forma es declarar la función como una función ejecutada inmediatamente o IFFE por sus siglas en inglés

```js
(function coinConvert(dollar = 50) {

soles = dollar * 3.25;

 pesosMexicanos = dollar * 18;

 pesosChilenos = dollar * 660;

console.log(soles, pesosMexicanos, pesosChilenos);       
})()
```

Referencia

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/IIFE